Calculation of displacement field from a strain field
I am trying to calculate the displacement field from a given strain field in 3D. It is quite a cumbersome calculation, as presented in Applied mechanics of solids by Bower;
\begin{equation}
    u_i(x) = \int_{x_0}^x U_{ij}(x,\xi)d\xi_j
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    U_{ij}(x,\xi) = \varepsilon_{ij} + (x_k - \xi_k)\left(\frac{\partial \varepsilon_{ij}(\xi)}{\partial \xi_k} - \frac{\partial \varepsilon_{kj}(\xi)}{\partial \xi_i} \right)
\end{equation}
where the $u_i$ is the displacements in direction $i$. Let's look at displacements in one particular direction, say $i=3$, along a straight line parallel to the axis $x_1$, say from $(0,0,0)$ to $(L,0,0)$. Several terms are zero and you are left with this;
\begin{equation}
    u_3(x) = \int_0^{x} \varepsilon_{31}(\xi) d\xi + \int_0^{x} (x - \xi)(\varepsilon_{31,1} - \varepsilon_{11,3}) d\xi .
\end{equation}
Rewriting;
\begin{equation}
    u_3(x) = \int_0^{x} \varepsilon_{31}(\xi) d\xi + x \int_0^{x} (\varepsilon_{31,1} - \varepsilon_{11,3}) d\xi 
    - \int_0^{x} (\varepsilon_{31,1} - \varepsilon_{11,3}) \xi d\xi
\end{equation}
Now this is not that difficult to calculate. We have also made the assumption that the displacement and rotation are zero at $(0,0,0)$.
Here is my question, what are the physical meanings of these three terms?
The first term is the sum of shears along the integration line. That kind of makes sense.
The second and the third terms are more complicated. From the definition, it looks like some sort of rotation I suppose? But what exactly is the physical meaning of the spatial derivative of a strain component? What comes when they are integrated as such, along a line?
